# Fuel profile for Apollo 11

Tags: the-moon, apollo-program, fuel, landing

I downloaded a dozen of NASA documents about post-flight analysis of Apollo 11 mission, but I cannot find a table or a plot of fuel usage and remains;

Some of the documents which I found:

- http://www.ibiblio.org/apollo/Documents/19730023018.pdf
- https://www.ibiblio.org/apollo/Documents/19720018205.pdf
- https://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/nasa58040.pdf
- https://elib.dlr.de/140508/1/apollo11_reloaded.pdf

In the last one there is thrust plot, which I can approximately use to determine the fuel mass plot, but isn't there any document around already plotting such data?

My main objective is to figure out **how much fuel was available at "low gate"**, but also this moment is not very clear, it varies between documents; according to [this one](https://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/nasa58040.pdf) (page 8), low gate should have occurred at 10:06 (606s), but I think it does not fit with fig. 16 in [this document](https://elib.dlr.de/140508/1/apollo11_reloaded.pdf), where throttle profile changes at 505s.

Some data I found about the descent engine:

- Full throttle: 45050 N
- Exhausts speed: 3000 m/s
- Specific impulse: 305 s

--> DeltaMass = 45050/3000 = 15 kg/s

I would like to write my own lunar lander simulator based on real data and tunable engine.